# Make dropdown sort list

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have this php code with a drop down pulling info from the database but cannot seem to figure out how to get the drop down selection to sort the list...

The drop down is showing the course name as the label but when selected needs to sort the list by course id.

[Visit Here to see the table in action](http://www.ems-complete.com/preentrancereport.php)

```
<?php 
        $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','emscompl_paramed','PASSOWRD) or die(mysql_error());

        $selectdb = mysql_select_db('emscompl_joom1283',$connect);

        $sel = "SELECT us.fullname, s . *
FROM registered_users AS `us`
LEFT OUTER JOIN course_students AS s ON s.userid = us.userid";
        $ressel = mysql_query($sel);

        $fetchsel = mysql_fetch_array($ressel);

        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.titiel {
    font-weight: bold;
}

td {
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    text-align:center;
}
 th {
        background-color:#000000;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#fff; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="titiel">Pre-Entrance Document Report</p>
<p> Please Select Course for Report</p>
  <form method="post" action="preentrancereportsorted.php">
        <label for="select"><select name="course" value="Select" size="1">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM courses"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id=$row["id"];
                $course=$row["coursename"]; 
                $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$course;
        }
        ?>
            <option>
                <? echo $options ?>
                </option>
            </select>
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Generate Report">
  </form>
<table width="1246" height="56">
  <tr>
    <th width="147" height="50">Student Name</td>
    <th width="15">R</th>
    <th width="18">M</th>
    <th width="18">L</th>
    <th width="81">Background</th>
    <th width="83">Drug Screen</th>
    <th width="112">Clear Background</th>
    <th width="113">Clean Drug Screen</th>
    <th width="97">Student Info</th>
    <th width="88">School App</th>
    <th width="117">Professional Recomendation</th>
    <th width="119">Reasonable Accomadations</th>
    <th width="59">Drivers Licesnse</th>
    <th width="91">High School Diploma</th>
  </tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ressel)) { ?>
    <td width="146" height="50"><?php echo $row['fullname'];?></td>
    <td width="17"><?php echo $row['entrancereadingscore'];?></td>
    <td width="17"><?php echo $row['mathscore'];?></th>
    <td width="17"><?php echo $row['locatinginfoscore'];?></td>
    <td width="84"> <?php echo $row['backcalc'];?></td>
    <td width="79"><?php echo $row['drugcalc'];?></td>
    <td width="113"><?php if ($row['clearbackground']='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no";
    }
    ?></td>
    <td width="114">
    <?php if ($row['cleardrugtest']=='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="96">
    <?php if ($row['studentinformationsheet']=='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="89">
    <?php if ($row['schoolapplication']=='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="118">
    <?php if ($row['professionalreco']=='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="119">
    <?php if ($row['reasonableaccom']=='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="58">
    <?php if ($row['driverlicesnce']=='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="91">
    <?php if ($row['highschooldip']=='1')
    {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No";
    }
    ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort your select box by id, then definitely use "ORDER BY" as Pachonk says above.

Also, I've noticed that your PHP below:

```
         <option>
            <? echo $options ?>
         </option>
```

is outputting:

```
<option>
<option value="Some id">some text
<option value="some other id">some other text
... repeat for all options
</option>
```

You should remove the first  from around the PHP (you are placing an  tag in the php echo statement anyway) and place the  tag in your php code above so that every  has an

like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id=$row["id"];
            $course=$row["coursename"]; 
            $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$course . "</option>";
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ added these
    }
    ?>

            // removed <option>
          <? echo $options ?>
             // removed </option>
          </select>
```

Of course, you could just have the php in the while clause output your option right there and then too.

Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: Ok I made the changes that you recommended... (greatly appreciated)... However I am curious how I can store the selected value to sort the table below the dropdown... ie.. If Jan 2013 AEMT course was selected than I only need the students from that class to show in the table... I would like to do this with the 'id' of the class

Comment: Hi Joshua.The <option> tag itself will send the the id in the code above by setting it as the Value. You can get it by doing something like `$courseID = $_POST['course'];`
You grab the value of the option through the name of the SELECT list.
From this you would then echo out the table of students using a SELECT query like: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE id=" . $courseID;`